# Python-simpy bitwise or

Tags: python, simpy

Now I learn the `simpy` library of python.
Could you explain me why `bitwise-or` is used in this [example](https://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/bank_renege.html). Why we can't use simple `or` statement.

```
results = yield req | env.timeout(patience)
```

Comment: It would help to have a little more context, what is stored in req for example? And what does env return? Knowing what they are might help explain the benefit of bitwise or'ing them. Also, is there any chance it's an error in the example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From SimPy's documentation of [Core Event Types](http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_reference/simpy.events.html#simpy.events.Event)

> This class also implements **and**() (&) and **or**() (|). If you
>   concatenate two events using one of these operators, a Condition event
>   is generated that lets you wait for both or one of them.

This implies that `req` and `env.timeout(patience)` are both events and we'll yield the first one that occurs.  I.e.

```
results = yield (req | env.timeout(patience))
```

To answer your original question, it appears you can use `or` instead but that might not make what's really going on any clearer and lead to editing errors if one assumes it's a regular old `or`.

Comment: You can only use the bitwise operators `&` and `|`, but not the keywords `and` and `or`.

Comment: @cdlane Could you help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072808/simpy-time-before-resource-is-released